# conflit key On EntityFramework code firsr

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, foreign-key-relationship

hi i have problem with key on EF, i have class(timelineitem) that contain have relation (one to many)with other class (messag) , buzztimelineitem cantain propertie (messagid) and prprtie of navigation (messag), when i create new timelineitem and try to do this :

```
     timeline.BuzzMessageId = listid.BuzzMessageId
```

i have exception that tell me there is conflict with table messag, and when i try to do this :

```
     timeline.BuzzMessage = list_msg[i]; (list_msg list of messag )
```

i have new row in table messag with same prpertie but different messagid , can you tell me please wath's the matter with this;

Comment: What is the exception exactly? Does a message with the supplied `BuzzMessageId` exist in the database?

Comment: yes BuzzMessageId existe in the database , i think that the probleme is to the msg in the list_msg in the same context of timeline, do you know how to do it ? note that i use the pattern repository and unit f work !! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to attach the `list_msg[i]` to the context which might solve the problem of the new row being created in the messages table:

```
context.Messages.Attach(list_msg[i]);
timeline.BuzzMessage = list_msg[i];
```

Comment: thanks MR Slauma , but as i say, i use repository pattern , so i can't access directly the context !!

Comment: @ucef: Then just create a repository method which can access the context and call `repo.AttachToMessages(...)` or something.